# Conviction before trial

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that expresses the idea that someone has been convicted before trial, either in the media or by public opinion?

Comment: Given that the authority responsible for convictions has yet to carry out the process by which they typically convict, then it's hard to see that there would be a word for this.  It would be different if that authority tried to get the trial to decide a pre-determined outcome (*that* happens all the time), or if the authority didn't feel the need to hold a trial (that happens too).  Or maybe the idea you're trying to get at is more where some party *other than* the authority with power to convict has the matter settled in their own minds.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there is no word for this, because it doesn't really exist.

You might have heard the colloquial phrase "tried in the court of public opinion" or "convicted by the court of public opinion" but that does not literally occur. When people say that, it is merely a colourful way of saying "everyone thinks he's guilty and isn't afraid to say so".

The only time people are literally convicted (punished) like this is called "mob justice" or vigilantism.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is, that person has been [prejudiced against](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prejudice+against).
Although the word [prejudice](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prejudice) is nowadays used in other contexts, not together with awaiting trial, it clearly stems from the situation you are asking about.

Comment: It does not imply conviction, merely bias. Is there a way to imply the conviction bit?

Comment: Common use of "prejudice" might not imply conviction but the word itself definitely does. "Pre" is a prefix meaning beforehand and "judice" is literally a Latin word meaning judgement.

Comment: @Digital Chris: That is what I meant, but you formulated it better.

Answer (score 0):

*Prejudge*, perhaps.

It doesn't necessarily imply guilt, though it might in the right context.